# How to run the django web server even after closing the shell on Amazon Linux

Tags: django, linux, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I'm running a Django application on my Amazon Linux instance using the below command:

`python manage.py runserver ec2-instance-ip.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000`

I want the application to be running even after I quit the shell. How do I run this web server even after quitting the shell on Amazon Linux?

I tried using the `&` as shown below, but it didn't work.

`python manage.py runserver ec2-instance-ip.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000 &`

Comment: You could use the [Screen Command](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Screen/).

Comment: You should deploy it to amazon. I think follow this video will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjrfUO91wfc

Answer (score 4):

Running `python manage.py ...` is how you run in development, but it's not how you run on a web server. You need to deploy your application.

Take a look at [Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/).

Answer (score 2):

Install screen with below command
Screen is basically a tool which runs the process always, even we exit.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screen
```

For details you can see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

Create a screen for you command, so your command can run as a daemon.

```
screen -S <processName> //Process name could be any random name for your process.
```

To enter inside screen.

```
screen -r <processName>
```

Now you are inside screen and can run your command here.

```
python manage.py runserver ec2-instance-ip.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000
```

Now exit screen: `ctrl+a and then d`

You can create multiple screens as many you want and can any time list them by command:

```
screen -ls
```

**!important:** this is not recommended for Production server.
Look this to run Python app on production server: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!